# Google Signin unclickable and freezes in login on mobile only

Tags: javascript, android, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin

I've implemented the Google Signin functionality and it works fine on any desktop. It used to work fine on mobile as well, but since recently it is showing two types of weird behavior:

1. If I try to click the button on Chrome for Android, I have to tap it at least 5 times until it responds. I've used remote debugging but there are no errors. Even weirder, if I click on the button through remote debugging it responds instantly. No other element on my website shows this behavior.
2. When an existing user clicks the button to login, it opens a new tab to accounts.google.com which stays white. In the background, the original tab is actually being logged in, however the user can't see this cause the "white" tab is the active one.

The console shows no errors at all, and on desktop everything works fine. I am clueless... Any idea where I should start looking?

My code for the button:

```
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
    data-clientid="{{ CLIENT_ID }}"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
```

Signin Javascript:

```
  function signInCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['code']) {

      var state = encodeURIComponent('{{ STATE }}');
      var code = encodeURIComponent(authResult['code']);          

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/signup/gauth',
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'Success') {
            console.log('Logged in');
          }
        },
        processData: false,
        data: 'code='+code+'&state='+state
      });
    } else if (authResult['error']) {
      console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works on all platforms without issues. I didn't do the styling of the button yet, but the process works.

Head of page:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
<script>
var googleUser = {};
function startApp() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '{{ CLIENT_ID }}',
        // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
    });
  });
};
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #customBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #4285f4;
    color: white;
    width: 190px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #customBtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span.label {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  span.icon {
    background: url('/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png') transparent 5px 50% no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    border-right: #2265d4 1px solid;
  }
  span.buttonText {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 42px;
    padding-right: 42px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Use the Roboto font that is loaded in the <head> */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
</style>
```

Button:

```
<div id="gSignInWrapper">
<div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="buttonText">Google Sign-in</span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.customGPlusSignIn').click(function() {
    // signInCallback defined in step 6.
    auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(signInCallback);
  });
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function signInCallback(authResult) {
  console.log(authResult)
  if (authResult['code']) {

    var state = encodeURIComponent('{{ STATE }}');
    var code = encodeURIComponent(authResult['code']);          

    // Send the code to the server
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/signup/gauth',
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(result) {
        if (result == 'Success') {
          console.log('Logged in');{% endif %}
        }
      },
      processData: false,
      data: 'code='+code+'&state='+state
    });
  } else if (authResult['error']) {
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}

function signOut() {
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    console.log('User signed out.');
    window.location = "/user/logout"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the older version of Google Sign-in. You might want to [try starting from here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).

I [hosted the demo here](https://gusclass.com/demo/button2).

**Includes / client configuration**

```
<head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"></meta>
</head>
```

**Code for the button target**

```
<body>
  <!-- ... --> 
  <div id="gConnect">
    <div id="signin-button"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... --> 
</body>
```

**Code for the initialization / rendering the button**

```
function startApp() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {
      gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
          fetch_basic_profile: false });
      gapi.auth2.init({fetch_basic_profile: false,
          scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'}).then(
            function (){
              console.log('init');
              auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
              auth2.isSignedIn.listen( function() {
                  console.log(auth2.currentUser.get());
                });
              auth2.then(function(resp){
                  console.log(auth2.currentUser.get());
                });
            });
    });
  });
}
```

**Offline Access**

For offline access, you need to call [auth2.grantOfflineAccess](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergrantofflineaccesswzxhzdk106scopeswzxhzdk107). Note that this will always show a consent screen to the user so it should be used in substitution for auth2.signIn() in circumstances where you don't have a refresh token on your backend server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your code above didn't work but you were right that updating to a newer version would solve the issue. I solved the problem by migrating to the newer version and switching to a custom button. Will post working code in a sec.

Comment: What I think caused your code not to work, is that I require offline access as well, which it wasn't giving.

Comment: Offline access is different, to do offline you now need to call auth2.grantOfflineAccess

Comment: Yap, figured that out by now. But you were right that migrating to a newer version would solve the issue. Thanks!